# how to get each div to call images from the folder it was told to get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 divs that preview images from a folder every 3 seconds. they all call the images from the same folder called  "pictures", i want to have each div get images from its own folder i assign it to. So those three divs would have their own folder to call images, but cant figure it out. I really need your help...

```
function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById("img").src = image;
           document.getElementById("img2").src = image;
            document.getElementById("img3").src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "pictures/" + "1.jpg";
      images[1] = "pictures/" + "2.jpg";
      for(var y=2;y<4;y++){
      images[y]= "pictures/" + (y+1) + ".jpg";
      }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="large_ad"><img id="img" src="pictures/1.jpg">7</div>
<div class="large_ad"><img id="img2" src="pictures/1.jpg">8</div>
<div class="large_ad"><img id="img3" src="pictures/1.jpg">9</div>
```

Comment: how is the structure... whether all the folders have images with the same name... what are the folder names

Comment: @user3440259 Does the piece in post work?

Comment: @ArunPJohny P Johnyeach folder will be named diffrent. ex:(folder1, folder 2, folder3) and the images inside the folders would be ex:(1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg) so the dives would call the pictures from the folder it was told to call